# Can I move my SD card with Buster from a Pi 3 to a Pi 4?

Tags: sd-card, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-os-buster

To get better performance, I want my existing setup on my Pi 3 moved directly to a Pi 4. Can I just switch the SD card from the Pi 3 to the Pi 4 for it to work properly?

The SD card contains a fresh install of Buster, not an upgrade from a previous version of Raspi OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes the files in the /boot partition are for a vast majority of the machines produced that will run that image. If you look in there you will see all of the model .dtb files named after the machine it will boot on, the Pi 3 & 4 included in it. My Pi 4 which runs the pure Debian as an example of what it will boot on.

```
root@buster-raspi:~# ll /boot/firmware/
total 119688
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    23435 Feb  8 15:47 bcm2711-rpi-4-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    13990 Feb  8 15:47 bcm2837-rpi-3-a-plus.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    14250 Feb  8 15:47 bcm2837-rpi-3-b.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    14622 Feb  8 15:47 bcm2837-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    13624 Feb  8 15:47 bcm2837-rpi-cm3-io3.dtb
```

Edit: And you should just be able to take your existing card and boot it in Pi 4 because of this universal boot if the Pi 4 files are there.